# jquery .load() same content after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple content loader, where I load content of html file into  element. That is working fine. But when I load content, then JS in content is not loaded because it is defined in main (index.html) document ready function.

### Question:

**How to load content where after page refresh it will remain in div?**

*Note: Prefer JS solution.*

**HTML:**

index.html

```
<ul id="debug_menu">
    <li>content1</li>
    <li>content2</li>
    <li>content3</li>
</ul>

<div id="zone"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
/* Content loader */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#debug_menu li").click(function() {

        $content = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery('#zone').load('content/' + $content + '.html');

    });

});

//Edit:

jQuery(".dial").knob();
```

**content1.html:**

```
<input value="90" class="dial">
```

*Note: using http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ plugin*

Comment: After page refresh I think you can't store your content to put in your div anymore.
If you use session or cookies, try put your data in Session and when page refresh div can take it out

Comment: What do you mean by "JS in content is not loaded"? Can you share the content code?

Comment: if JS is present in index than why you have to load?????

Comment: @UziKilon I added `content1.html` to show you what is there. As you see I load `.knob()` function in it, and it is not loaded when I `load()` content into div.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat see edit. JS `.knob()` in content1.html is not loaded when I load content into div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this plugin: https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

to store content variable into **session**.

```
/* Content loader */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#debug_menu li").click(function() {

        $content = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery.session.set('content', $content);
        jQuery('#zone').load('content/' + $content + '.html',
                function() {
                    initial_loader();
                }
        );

    });

    $s = jQuery.session.get('content');
    jQuery('#zone').load('content/' + $s + '.html',
            function() {
                initial_loader();
            }
    );

});

function initial_loader() {

    jQuery(".dial").knob();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#debug_menu li").click(function() {
                $content = jQuery(this).text();
                jQuery('#zone').load('content/' + $content + '.html', function() {
                    jQuery(".dial").knob();//initialize new one
                });

            });

        });
        jQuery(".dial").knob();
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#debug_menu li").click(function() {
                    $content = jQuery(this).text();
                    jQuery('#zone').load('content/' + $content + '.html', function() {
                        initial_loader();//initialize new one
                    });

                });
                initial_loader();
            });
            function initial_loader(){
                jQuery(".dial").knob();
            }
```

Comment: your suggestion is working but I have A LOT of javascript and A LOT of content to load and It is not optional solution for me to load all JS again just for loading content. +1 for effort.

Comment: just create function and load that function

Answer (score 0):

When you load content, you should also manipulate the current page URL in a way that does not cause a reload. This basically means changing the hash part (`#something`). On page load, you only have to check the current hash and load the right content.

You can also use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) with the same logic, it gives you more options to manipulate any part of the URL without a reload. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/history) is not the best yet though, but you can use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/) as a wrapper.

Advantages: both methods will make your content linkable and make the browser history usable (back, forward buttons will work) other than fixing your reload problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You have to store which div is loaded etc.
Solutions where you can store something:

1. Cookie
2. Localstorage
3. Hashtag